# What exactly happen when we execute truffle migrate --reset?

Tags: solidity, truffle, dapps

I have a old ABI generated by executing `truffle migrate`.
Now I update the code and generate a new ABI by `truffle migrate --reset`.

What exactly happens by executing `truffle migrate --reset` ?

What about the data storage of previous smart contract ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your migrations run from the beginning.

Using `ganache` blockchain (for this example), you can check this information at the bottom of your contract's `.json` files.

Before `--reset`:

```
  "networks": {
    "5777": {
      "events": {},
      "links": {},
      "address": "0x2429A2d4d4eE68C33a08e0490f5E3daf9d3329Ef",
      "transactionHash": "0x5b8a2e62e029665eebb57e9679dee738f88c1505280f90dc4942a302782ef4ed"
    }
```

After `--reset`:

```
"networks": {
    "5777": {
      "events": {},
      "links": {},
      "address": "0x31D381295EBed6D8834F5CafbfeD559Dc0AD02cC",
      "transactionHash": "0x7d5c9fa517fab0730e6ae06b576e91d2f3a44504c97e100b7f3375d05b9eaeec"
    }
```

As you can see there is a new address of the same contract. The data storage of the previous contract will remain but you won't communicate with it. From now on you will call the new contract address when you make a transaction.

This is easy to track in Ropsten, Rinkeby... and also possible in ganache but it depends on your configuration.

Comment: Thank you @alberto and let's say If I developed one social media platform and successfully deployed on live network. After some days I updated the code and migrate --reset and  deployed again  (the new JSON) to the live network. Does it means previous smart contract works perfectly fine ? new one is act as new smart contract ?

Comment: @Suria What you deploy to the blockchain is the smart contract, so the previous contract still works fine and the new deployed too.

Comment: Then how to convey the community  to use new one ?

Comment: thank you so much for your response. I have cleared my questions.

Comment: @Suria Probably if the update corrects bugs, the community will accept the new contract but I consider that question more complicated...

Comment: Thanks for everything @alberto.